# Apple Script to output text and links to spreadsheet

Tags: text, copy, applescript

My goal is to get a Apple script running that can pull text from the top 50 apps and put them into a spread sheet with a few different columns. One for rank, App Name, and download link.

Heres the link: http://www.apple.com/itunes/charts/free-apps/

I'm not the best apple scripture but any advice or code would be VERY much appreciated. Thanks for listening!

Comment: your question is vague. Help other users help you by including more detail on your end goal and even a little pseudo-code. The more thought you put in, the more help you will get back.

Comment: Thanks @DaveA . My end goal is to have a applescript that would allow me to select text on http://www.appsmenow.com/iphone_apps/free, copy the top 50 and paste the results in a Numbers spreadsheet and have the text fall into the proper categories. This would include the apps ranking, app name, company name,and download link. This would save me a lot of time considering I'd have to copy paste each category every week with multiple sets of 50 :/ Hope that helped you figure out what I'm trying to do, thanks. P.s. I basically want to copy the text, format it, and make it into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have numbers but I'm sure you can figure out the rest...

```
tell application "Safari"
    set myUrls to do JavaScript "var hitList = [];
    for (i = 0; i<50; i++)
    {
    hitList.push(document.getElementsByTagName('strong')[i].parentNode.childNodes[1].href)
    }
    hitList;" in document 1

    set appNames to do JavaScript "var hitList = [];
    for (i = 0; i<50; i++)
    {
    hitList.push(document.getElementsByTagName('strong')[i].parentNode.childNodes[2].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
    }
    hitList;" in document 1
end tell

display dialog "1st App name: " & item 1 of appNames & return & "1st URL: " & item 1 of myUrls
```